# How to subtract cylinder from a cube, add bevel and make it all smooth

Tags: modifiers

So I have this kind of cube and I need to subtract half of the cylinder from it. The cylinder is centered in the z-axis. The boolean operation seems to work fine but on top of that I want to bevel all my edges of the cube and smooth the semi-hole I just carved before.

Eveything I try results in glitches in the mesh.
What am I doing wrong?

I'm using blender 2.91.0 beta

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend starting with [autosmooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/structure.html#properties) along with a [weighted normals modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/weighted_normal.html#weighted-normal-modifier) to help the result after
a [bevel modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html#bevel-modifier).

Here is my cube's modifier stack:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Tried your suggestions but I can't even get the bevel to show. I attached the blend file to my question. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: @zephirus if you look [closely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qke3V.gif)  you will see that bevel is indeed there.

Comment: it's a bug of 2.91.0 beta. I just opened it in blender 2.90.1 and it shows.

Comment: Interesting. I am using 2.91 latest stable

Comment: Also, in 2.90.1 the boolean cuts an hole in the cube. I will install the same version you have.

Comment: Ok, with 2.90.1 latest stable I'm getting the same results you have. Btw, to get even more smooth curves, what are my options? Use a cylinder with more vertices or is there another way similar to subdivision surface?

Comment: It’s just default cube and default cylinder. Nothing more than the images I posted.

Comment: My question was about how to smooth even more the curvature - I added a second image as an example.

Comment: Not working anymore when I create a new scene. It seems like a blender bug. When I use "Exact" for boolean I get a perfect cut but Bevel does nothing. If I use Fast, the cut is not done but I get the bevels. Damn!

Comment: Might depend on the Z position of the cylinder. If edges intersect it can fault the bevel modifier. try inserting a weld modifier between the two others and increase the weld threshold distance

Comment: Thanks again. That solved the issue. Now I only have to get a way to smooth the curve. It's not smooth at all. Added a new screenshoot with a shining matcap

Comment: Please ask a different question for different issues. Comments are not intended for discussion and should not be continued for longer than necessary.